# Show that a solution of the wave equation is time independent

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, wave-equation

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $u$ solve the wave equation $u_{tt}-\Delta{u}=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic with $h(x)=u(x,0)$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$. Show that $u$ is time independent.

I have:

Since $u$ solves the wave equation $u_{tt}-\Delta{u}=0$. At the point $(x,0)$ we have $0-\Delta{h}=0$. Because $h$ is harmonic, $h$ also solves the wave equation.

From here I am not sure how to continue, I am not even sure if this is correct. I would appreciate some hints to know how to proceed.

Comment: What "the wave equation"? An homogenoeus one, say $\;u_{tt}+c^2u_{xx}=0\;$ ? But then what is $\;c\;$ ? Or perhaps an non-homogeneous one?

Comment: Sorry, a homogenous wave equation where c=1

Comment: If $h$ solves the wave equation, then by linearity $u - h$ solves the wave equation. What are the boundary conditions that $u-h$ satisfies?

Comment: Would $w:=u-h$ satisfy $w(x,0)=0$ and $w_t(x,0)=0$? And I would have to show that $w=0$?